# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

i am trying to learn open source project on GitHub.here [here is the link to project](https://github.com/woemler/spring-blog) I can execute mvn clean install successfully.but the problem is when I go to deploy using -DskipTests=true it gives errors below.so how can I setup this type of project locally and please help how to successfully deploy it  errors below--->

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Spring Blog 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ spring-blog ---



                          `......`                          
                        `............``                     
                           ``............`                  
                                `............`              
                                    `............`          
      `:++:.`                           `...........`       
      :++oooo+:.`                           `......--.      
      :+++ooooooo+:.`                           .----.      
      :+++++ooooooooo+:.`                       `----.      
      :++++.`-:+ooooooooo+:.`                   `----.      
      :++++.    `-:+ooooooooo+                  `----.      
      :++++.        `-:+oooooo`                 `----.      
      :++++.            `-:+oo`                 `----.      
      :++++.    --`         `-                  `----.      
      :++++.    +oo+:.                          `----.      
      :++++.    +oooo:                          `----.      
      :++++.    .:/+o:                          `----.      
      :++++.       `..                          `----.      
      :++++-`                                  `.:---.      
      :+//////:.`                          `.-:::::::.      
      `-//////////:-`                  `.-::::::::::-`      
         `.-//////////:-`          `.-::::::::::-.`         
             `.-//////////:-.` `.-::::::::::-.`             
                 `.-://///////::::::::::-.`                 
                     `.-///////:::::-.`                     
                         `.-:/::-.`                         



2016-09-19 10:07:11.150  INFO 8368 --- [  restartedMain] me.woemler.springblog.Application        : Starting Application on yogesh-GL552VW with PID 8368 (/media/yogesh/68BFB7DA4E8F9CBB/TEMP/spring-blog-master/target/classes started by yogesh in /media/yogesh/68BFB7DA4E8F9CBB/TEMP/spring-blog-master)
2016-09-19 10:07:11.153  INFO 8368 --- [  restartedMain] me.woemler.springblog.Application        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-19 10:07:11.202  INFO 8368 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4d1cba86: startup date [Mon Sep 19 10:07:11 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-19 10:07:11.619  WARN 8368 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [me.woemler.springblog.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
2016-09-19 10:07:11.625 ERROR 8368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [me.woemler.springblog.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at me.woemler.springblog.Application.main(Application.java:21) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:291) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:231) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

2016-09-19 10:07:11.627  INFO 8368 --- [  restartedMain] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/media/yogesh/68BFB7DA4E8F9CBB/TEMP/spring-blog-master/target/classes/]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.844s
Finished at: Mon Sep 19 10:07:11 IST 2016
Final Memory: 11M/212M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project spring-blog: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Comment: please share the complete command resulting in failure and the pom.xml contents. link to projects are not useful unless you share the details

Comment: As @nullpointer suggested, share the command you have used. If you want to execute/run application then use `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing servlet-api dependency as you can see in

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
... 25 common frames omitted
```

The dependency "jstl" has a transient dependency to servlet-api but somewhere in the dependency chain there is a probably a "provided" scope so the dependency is not propagated.

"platform-bon" defines "servlet-api" so you just have to add to your pom

```
 <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: the pom in the repo do not have reference any to "javax.servlet-api" artifact. If you are using a different one please modify your question as suggested @nullpointer. It will make the process more consistent also for future users.

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Property 'tagName' not found on type java.lang.String while accessing application url-->http://localhost:8080/admin/tags